# VBA - count occurence each char in range of cells

Tags: vba, count, char

I want to create VBA code which should count occurence each letter in range (eg A2:A10

It will be easier to describy by showing you how it should work:
[image]

Output should ignore duplicates.
What I've built is below. Its wrong, but I've stucked at this little project, and I cannot move forward:

```
Sub TESTOWEMAKRO()


    Dim i As Long, licznik As Long, znak As String, r As Long



    For i = 2 To 10

        If i = 2 Then
            Range("N" & i) = znak

                For r = i To 10

                    If znak = Range("N" & r + 1) Then
                        licznik = licznik + 1
                        r = r + 1
                    Else
                        r = r + 2
                    End If

                        If r >= 10 Then

                            Range("P" & i).Value = licznik
                            Range("Q" & i).Value = znak
                        End If

                Next r

        'tutaj jesli bedzie powyzej 3

        End If


    Next i

End Sub
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### VBA Solution

1. Copy the range from `Column A` to `Column C`
2. Remove duplicates from `Column C`
3. Access `COUNTIF` function with `Application.WorksheetFunction`
4. Loop through unique values in `Column C`

You could also do this with `Advanced Filter` which would replace steps **1.** & **2.**

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") '<== Update sheet name
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long

LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("A1:A" & LRow).Copy ws.Range("C1")
ws.Range("C1:C" & LRow).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
ws.Range("D1") = "Count"

For i = 2 To ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("D" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A:A"), ws.Range("C" & i))
Next i

End Sub
```

---

### Non-VBA solution: `Pivot Table`

Just highlight your column `To Count` and insert pivot. Drag your only available field to the `Rows` field and `Values` field.

In photo, `Column C & D` are generated by macro and you can see the output of pivot, and pivot set up, to the far right.

[image]